# How to send a Protocol Buffer message over an SNS of AWS and decode the message appropriately to the subscriber in a FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, boto3, protocol-buffers, fastapi, amazon-sns

Apparently, I was able to send the message. However, it seems that when the message is received by the subscriber the encoding changes as it throws a `(Decode Error) Error parsing message`.

Also, I would expect not to do any decoding, as is supposed I send Binary type. Instead, I receive a string and I should do a decoding step.

The publisher.py

```
import boto3
from my_generated_pb2 import MyMessage

sns_client = boto3.client("sns")

message = MyMessage()
message.content = "Hello, SNS!"

response = sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn="TOPIC_ARN",
        Message='test',
        MessageAttributes={
            'ProtocolBuffer': {
                'DataType': 'Binary',
                'BinaryValue': message.SerializeToString()
            },
        }
    )
```

The subscriber.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from my_generated_pb2 import MyMessage

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/subscriber")
async def subscriber(request: Request):
    """
    Receives a message from SNS.
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    body = await request.json()
    if body['Type'] == "Notification":
        serialized_message = body['MessageAttributes']['ProtocolBuffer']['Value'].encode()
        message_obj = TransactionRequest()
        message_obj.ParseFromString(serialized_message)  # ERROR!
```

If you do the following it works:

```
from my_generated_pb2 import MyMessage

message = MyMessage()
message.content = "Hello, SNS!"
serialized_message = message.SerializeToString()

message_obj = MyMessage()
message_obj.ParseFromString(serialized_message)
```

That's why I suspect there is a bug in Boto or in the SNS or maybe just a misunderstanding of something :(